Isolates in Flutter for signal scanning
I am trying to move some heavy operations (like scanning and processing drones data being broadcasted) to isolates.
Following is my original implementation:
final class RemoteIDReceiverRepositoryImplementation
    implements RemoteIDReceiverRepository {
  @override
  Stream<Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>>
      get remoteIDStream {
    late final StreamController<
            Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>>
        remoteIDStreamController;

    late final StreamSubscription<MessageContainer> remoteIDStreamSubscription;

    final remoteIDEntities = <RemoteIDEntity>{};

    remoteIDStreamController =
        StreamController<Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>>(
      onListen: () {
        FlutterOpenDroneId.startScan(
          UsedTechnologies.Both,
        );

        void addNewRemoteIDEntityAndEmitNewEventUsing(
          RemoteIDEntity newRemoteIDEntity,
        ) {
          remoteIDEntities.add(
            newRemoteIDEntity,
          );

          remoteIDStreamController.add(
            Right(
              remoteIDEntities,
            ),
          );
        }

        remoteIDStreamSubscription = FlutterOpenDroneId.allMessages.listen(
          (messageContainer) {
            final currentRemoteIDEntity = RemoteIDEntity.fromOpenDroneID(
              messageContainer,
            );

            if (remoteIDEntities.isEmpty) {
              addNewRemoteIDEntityAndEmitNewEventUsing(
                currentRemoteIDEntity,
              );

              return;
            }

            if (remoteIDEntities.isNotEmpty) {
              for (var index = zero; index < remoteIDEntities.length; index++) {
                if (remoteIDEntities
                        .elementAt(
                          index,
                        )
                        .connection
                        .macAddress ==
                    currentRemoteIDEntity.connection.macAddress) {
                  final oldRemoteIDEntity = remoteIDEntities.elementAt(
                    index,
                  );

                  final newRemoteIDEntity = oldRemoteIDEntity.merge(
                    currentRemoteIDEntity,
                  );

                  remoteIDEntities
                    ..remove(
                      oldRemoteIDEntity,
                    )
                    ..add(
                      newRemoteIDEntity,
                    );

                  remoteIDStreamController.add(
                    Right(
                      remoteIDEntities,
                    ),
                  );

                  return;
                }
              }

              addNewRemoteIDEntityAndEmitNewEventUsing(
                currentRemoteIDEntity,
              );
            }
          },
          onError: (_) => remoteIDStreamController.add(
            Left(
              RemoteIDReceiverFailure(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      onCancel: () {
        FlutterOpenDroneId.stopScan();
        remoteIDStreamController.close();
        remoteIDStreamSubscription.cancel();
      },
    );

    return remoteIDStreamController.stream;
  }
}

I tried to move the heavy operations like receiveing the remoteIdEntities being broadcasted and processing it in a isolate as follows:
Modified remote_i_d_receiver_repository_implementation.dart:
`import 'dart:async' show StreamController, StreamSink, StreamSubscription;
import 'dart:async' show StreamController, StreamSink, StreamSubscription;
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart' show Either, Left, Right;
import 'package:flutter_opendroneid/flutter_opendroneid.dart'
    show FlutterOpenDroneId, UsedTechnologies;
import 'package:flutter_opendroneid/models/message_container.dart';
import 'package:sky_trade/core/errors/failures/remote_i_d_receiver_failure.dart';
import 'package:sky_trade/core/resources/numbers/networking.dart' show zero;
import 'package:sky_trade/features/remote_i_d_receiver/domain/entities/remote_i_d_entity.dart'
    show RemoteIDEntity;
import 'package:sky_trade/features/remote_i_d_receiver/domain/repositories/remote_i_d_receiver_repository.dart';

import '../remote_id_scanner.dart';

final class RemoteIDReceiverRepositoryImplementation
    implements RemoteIDReceiverRepository {
  Isolate? _scannerIsolate;
  ReceivePort? _receivePort;

  @override
  Stream<Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>>
  get remoteIDStream {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    final rootIsolateToken = RootIsolateToken.instance;
    final remoteIDStreamController =
    StreamController<Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>>();
    // final remoteIDEntities = <RemoteIDEntity>{};

    // void addNewRemoteIDEntityAndEmitNewEventUsing(RemoteIDEntity entity) {
    //   remoteIDEntities.add(entity);
    //   remoteIDStreamController.add(Right(remoteIDEntities));
    // }

    // Start the isolate and listen for messages
    Isolate.spawn(
          (List<Object?> args) {
        final sendPort = args[0]! as SendPort;
        final rootToken = args[1]! as RootIsolateToken;

        RemoteIDScanner.startScanning(sendPort, rootToken);
      },
      [receivePort.sendPort, rootIsolateToken], // Pass both SendPort and RootIsolateToken
    ).then((isolate) {
      _scannerIsolate = isolate;

      // Listen for messages from the isolate
      receivePort.listen((message) {
        if (message is SendPort) {
          // Save the isolate's SendPort to send messages (e.g., 'stop')
          final isolateSendPort = message;
          isolateSendPort.send('stop');
        } else if (message is Either<RemoteIDReceiverFailure, Set<RemoteIDEntity>>) {
          // Process messages from the isolate
          message.fold(
                (failure) => print('Failure: $failure'),
                (entities) => print('Detected entities: $entities'),
          );
        }
      });
    });

    return remoteIDStreamController.stream;
  }

  void _stopScanning() {
    if (_scannerIsolate != null) {
      _receivePort?.close();
      _scannerIsolate?.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
      _scannerIsolate = null;
      print('Scanner isolate stopped.');
    }
  }
}`

remote_id_scanner.dart:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_opendroneid/flutter_opendroneid.dart';
import 'package:flutter_opendroneid/models/message_container.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_opendroneid/flutter_opendroneid.dart';
import 'package:sky_trade/core/errors/failures/remote_i_d_receiver_failure.dart';
import 'package:sky_trade/features/remote_i_d_receiver/domain/entities/remote_i_d_entity.dart';

class RemoteIDScanner {
  static void startScanning(SendPort sendPort, RootIsolateToken rootIsolateToken) {
    // Initialize the binary messenger for platform channels in this isolate
    BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(rootIsolateToken);

    // Use a set to keep track of unique RemoteIDEntity objects
    final remoteIDEntities = <RemoteIDEntity>{};

    try {
      // Start scanning for drone messages
      FlutterOpenDroneId.startScan(UsedTechnologies.Both);
      print('Scanning started in isolate.');

      // Listen for messages from FlutterOpenDroneId
      final subscription = FlutterOpenDroneId.allMessages.listen(
            (messageContainer) {
          try {
            final newEntity = RemoteIDEntity.fromOpenDroneID(messageContainer);

            // Merge or add the new entity
            RemoteIDEntity? existingEntity;
            for (final entity in remoteIDEntities) {
              if (entity.connection.macAddress == newEntity.connection.macAddress) {
                existingEntity = entity;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (existingEntity != null) {
              remoteIDEntities
                ..remove(existingEntity)
                ..add(existingEntity.merge(newEntity));
            } else {
              remoteIDEntities.add(newEntity);
            }

            // Send the updated set of RemoteIDEntity objects back to the main thread
            sendPort.send(Right(remoteIDEntities));
          } catch (e) {
            // Send failure in case of errors
            sendPort.send(Left(RemoteIDReceiverFailure()));
          }
        },
        onError: (error) {
          sendPort.send(Left(RemoteIDReceiverFailure()));
        },
      );

      // Stop scanning and clean up when the isolate receives a "stop" message
      final isolateReceivePort = ReceivePort();
      sendPort.send(isolateReceivePort.sendPort);

      isolateReceivePort.listen((message) {
        if (message == 'stop') {
          subscription.cancel();
          FlutterOpenDroneId.stopScan();
          isolateReceivePort.close();
          print('Scanning stopped in isolate.');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      sendPort.send(Left(RemoteIDReceiverFailure()));
    }
  }
}


But , this is not working. It is supposed tot detect the drones being broadcasted and show it on the UI. But that is not happening. I have seen some error logs but i think there are more errors in the code.
The error logs:
Scanning started in isolate.
E/flutter ( 5300): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(1291)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5300): Unsupported operation: Background isolates do not support setMessageHandler(). Messages from the host platform always go to the root isolate.
E/flutter ( 5300): #0      BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler (package:flutter/src/services/_background_isolate_binary_messenger_io.dart:94:5)
E/flutter ( 5300): #1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:663:23)
E/flutter ( 5300): #2      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:824:24)
E/flutter ( 5300): #3      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:207:7)
E/flutter ( 5300): #4      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:837:19)
E/flutter ( 5300): #5      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:497:9)
E/flutter ( 5300): #6      FlutterOpenDroneId.startScan (package:flutter_opendroneid/flutter_opendroneid.dart:63:10)
E/flutter ( 5300): #7      RemoteIDScanner.startScanning (package:sky_trade/features/remote_i_d_receiver/data/remote_id_scanner.dart:26:26)
E/flutter ( 5300): #8      RemoteIDReceiverRepositoryImplementation.remoteIDStream.<anonymous closure> (package:sky_trade/features/remote_i_d_receiver/data/repositories/remote_i_d_receiver_repository_implementation.dart:43:25)
E/flutter ( 5300): #9      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)

I tried to add some console logs statement.
